# C# Event without Invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, events

im new to C# Event and i want to fire an event without getting a Cross-Thread error..

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class SampleTickEvent
{
private string passStr = string.Empty;
Timer t = new Timer(1000);

public delegate void ImageEventHandler(string s);
public event ImageEventHandler ImageEventTrigger;

public void Start(string ss)
{
    passStr = ss;
    t.Start();
    t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
}

public void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eea)
{
    ImageEventTrigger(passStr);
}
}
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SampleTickEvent ste = new SampleTickEvent();
        ste.Start("sample");
        ste.ImageEventTrigger += ste_ImageEventTrigger;
    }

    private void ste_ImageEventTrigger(string s)
    {
        Action act = () => listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        Invoke(act);
    }
```

is there another way that i will not put the Action act = () = ... and put listbox1.Items.Add(s) instead?

Comment: can't i put the Invoke in my SampleTickEvent Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `System.Timers.Timer`, trying using [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), which is written so that it raises the event *on the UI thread.*

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Windows Forms, you can use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer. The tick event executes in the UI Thread : http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/05/systemwindowsformstimer-vs.html

Answer (score 1):

No, `Timer`s operate on a thread from the thread pool, and so to safely modify your form controls, you need to use `Invoke`.

You could inline the action, but that's about it.

If you want to put the `Invoke` into the `SampleTickEvent.t_Elapsed` method, then you'll have to pass a `Control` as a handle into the `SampleTickEvent` first. Or, you could just create a new `Control` as a member of the the `SampleTickEvent` in its constructor, and call `Invoke` on that. I've done it that way before.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* change this option during application startup:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

This would go in whichever `Form` you're using as the main application thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead of `System.Timers.Timer`.

From above Msdn Link:

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.